# How does the variance appear in $\frac{E(X-\mu)^3}{\sigma^3}$

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, moment-generating-functions

I wanted to know how the variance appears in the following moment about the mean when calculating for skewness:
$\frac{E(X-\mu)^3}{\sigma^3}$

By expanding it we get:

$$\frac{E(X^3)-3\mu[E(X^2)+\mu E(X)]-\mu^3}{\sigma^3} $$

I understand that $Var(X) = \sigma^2 = E[X^2]-\mu^2$

Though I do not understand why $E(X^2)+\mu E(X)=\sigma^2$ and would really appreciate some clarification.

Comment: Because $\mu=\Bbb EX$? You made a typo: $\Bbb VX=\sigma^2=\Bbb E[X^2]-\mu^{\color{red}2}$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I was doubtful because the variance has a 'minus' sign, and the equation above has an 'addition', so does it work either way then?

Comment: You expanded the binomial incorrectly. It should be $\Bbb E[X^3]-3\mu\Bbb E[X^2]+3\mu^2\Bbb EX-\mu^3=\Bbb E[X^3]-3\mu(\Bbb E[X^2]\color{red}-\mu\Bbb EX)-\mu^3$.

Comment: And it most certainly does *not* work either way. An equality cannot be true with both a non-zero term under $+$ and the same non-zero term under $-$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Thanks for the pointer it all makes better sense now!

Comment: $Z=(X-\mu)/\sigma$ is just to centralize and descale the random variable (to have variance $1$).  Kurtosis is then defined just as $E[Z^3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $E[X] = \mu$, hence
$$
E[X^2] - \mu E[X] =E[X^2] - E[X] E[X] = E[X^2] - E^2[X] = Var(X)  =\sigma^2
$$
Therefore, the skewness is
\begin{align}
\frac{E(X-\mu)^3}{\sigma^3} &= \frac{E[X^3] - 3\mu E[X^2] + 3\mu^2 E[X] - \mu^3}{\sigma^3}\\
& = \frac{E[X^3] - 3\mu ( E[X^2] - \mu E[X]) - \mu^3}{\sigma^3}\\
& = \frac{E[X^3] - 3\mu \sigma^2 - \mu^3}{\sigma^3}
\end{align}